# Why is the emf induced in a closed spiral in a time-changing magnetic field less than that induced in a closed loop of the same radius?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I don't get it. Is the area linked different?  Or is it something less?

This is the kind of closed spiral I'm thinking of:

[image]

Comment: This question is unclear. I would recommend a drawing for showing the configuration. I am not even sure what a closed spiral is. How can a spiral be closed?

Comment: @Dale I think the diagram from OP's post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/439914/) would describe the (strange) concept of closed spirals. Ideally, that could be edited into the question; I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably familiar with Faraday's law of induction:$$\varepsilon=-N\frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
$N$ is the number of turns in the coil. One way I like to think of Faraday's law is by visualizing a coil as $N$ distinct single-loops, each of which follows $\varepsilon_0=-\frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}t}$ (since we're *taking* $N=1$). Then, these independent potential sources are taken in series, and the final potential, $\varepsilon$, is $N\times\varepsilon_0$, because you add the individual voltages for a set of sources in series.

Let's say that the vector area of the closed loop is $S$, and the number of turns in that is $N$. For the spiral, we need to assume that there are $N$ loops too (i.e. the coil passes a certain 'starting' point $N$ times), and you mentioned that the *outer* radius will be the same as the closed loop's.

We can think of the spiral as a series of individual loops, whose radii decrease continuously. This isn't strictly exact, since a spiral isn't the same as a set of concentric circles, but it's a good approximation. Clearly, the outer coil's vector area will be $S$, since the radius is the same as the closed loop's, but each inner circle will have a smaller area, so the corresponding EMFs will be smaller, since for constant areas, $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}t}=S'\cos\theta\frac{\mathrm{d}B}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
And that's why their sum will be less than the emf for the conventional closed loop, 
 which is $N\times S\cos\theta\frac{\mathrm{d}B}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

<sub>It's nice that you fixed your closed question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/439914/); this one looks like it fits with the homework policy.</sub>

Comment: Wait, do you mean that I should assume a regular circular loop as the juxtaposition of several loops (all of the same radius), while the spiral is to be thought of as (again) a combination of loops, but with decreasing radii?

Comment: That might account for the lesser flux noticed.

Comment: @AabeshGhosh That's exactly what I was trying to say.